# Link para uma página externa não funciona

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, menu, link

No menu da página [www.wrccdesign.com.br](http://www.wrccdesign.com.br), o link **BLOG** que é um link externo que deverá levar para outra página, não funciona, isto é, ao clicar nada acontece.
Gostaria de saber como solucionar o problema. 
Fiz alguns testes, e pelo que percebi um JS está afetando a funcionalidade.

Comment: Olá Wagner, bem vindo ao Stack Overflow. Poste a porção relevante do código com problema (por exemplo, a tag `<a>` e o código JavaScript que está interferindo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa sua função tá bloqueando:

```
$('.templatemo-top-menu .navbar-nav a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var linkId = $(this).attr('href');
    scrollTo(linkId);
    if($('.navbar-toggle').is(":visible") == true){
        $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('toggle');
    }
    $(this).blur();
    return false;
});
```

Perceba, quando você usa o `e.preventDefault();` ele impede que o evento de `click` seja continuado. Você tem várias formas de resolver esse problema, eu acho que a melhor seria especificar os links que você quer que chame essa função, da seguinte maneira:

Adicione a classe `inpage` para todos os menus que dão scroll na pagina:

```
<a href="#templatemo-about" class="inpage">SOBRE</a>
```

Os que vão abrir externamente você deixa como tá:

```
<a href="http://www.wrccdesign.com.br/blog/" target="_blank">BLOG</a>
```

E depois adiciona um .inpage no final do seletor da sua função:

```
$('.templatemo-top-menu .navbar-nav a.inpage')
```

Comment: Me confundi na minha resposta, isto deve resolver.

Comment: AEEE! DEU CERTO! puts! obrigado mesmo! valeu a galera que comentou tb!

Comment: @WagnerRosati, se a resposta te ajudou, marque ela como solução, para que outras pessoas que tenham o mesmo problema que você também possam ser ajudadas!

Comment: @JuniorNunes7 man, obrigado, como posso marcar a resposta?

Comment: @WagnerRosati ao lado esquerdo dessa resposta tem 2 setas, uma pra baixo e uma pra cima, em baixo dessas setas tem um V, só clicar nele. Você pode ler mais aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/57573

Comment: legal, já cliquei...falando sobre UX, achei um pouco "escondido" esse "v" não dando a entender que se trata para esta finalidade...
abraços! obrigado!

Comment: Concordo com você @WagnerRosati, valeu!